# How to turn off auto-conversion to smart quotes in poedit?

Tags: poedit

While working on translations, I noticed that under very specific conditions, poedit automatically converts `"`(U+0022) to `“”`(U+201C, U+201D). I would like to turn this feature off, but cannot locate where I can toggle the feature in my config file. Are there other ways to do this?

My `net.poedit.Poedit.cfg` file. (Mac M1)

```
version=3.3.1
SID=xyz
first_launch=0
first_launch_t=1684809219
last_file_path=/Users/xyz/Desktop/comprehensive-rust/po
online_tm_contribute=forbid
splitter=257
sidebar_splitter=0.790972
sort_by=file-order
sort_group_by_context=0
sort_untrans_first=0
sort_errors_first=1
display_lines=0
[Parsers]
MigratedTo20=1
[TM]
search_paths=/Users/xyz:/usr/share/locale:/usr/local/share/locale
[sidebar]
dictionaries_ad_launches=4
dictionaries_ad_dismissed=yes
[windows]
[windows/mainwin]
x=-2560
y=52
w=2560
h=1360
maximized=0
```

Comment: Poedit does no such thing. Your operating system does, because you enabled that feature called Smart Quotes. See the Edit menu - in every single app on your Mac, not only in Poedit.

Comment: Edit > Substitutions > Smart Quotes, thank you